# Can I always rely on RVO by the compiler?

Tags: c++, return-value-optimization

I have a function for reading files into a string variable. And I am not sure what is a better way to implement it:

```
            void readFile(const std::filesystem::path& path, std::string& dest)
            {
                std::ifstream input(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
                if (!input.is_open())
                {
                    // throw exception
                }
                const std::size_t size = std::filesystem::file_size(path);
                std::string().swap(dest);
                dest.resize(size);
                input.read(&dest[0], size);
                input.close();
                if (input.fail() && !input.eof())
                {
                    // throw exception
                }
            }
```

Or:

```
            std::string readFile(const std::filesystem::path& path)
            {
                std::ifstream input(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
                if (!input.is_open())
                {
                    // throw exception
                }
                const std::size_t size = std::filesystem::file_size(path);
                std::string buffer(size, '\0');
                input.read(&buffer[0], size);
                input.close();
                if (input.fail() && !input.eof())
                {
                    // throw exception
                }
                return buffer;
            }
```

The files to be read might be several bytes to several hundreds of megabytes in size, so read operations might be quite expensive. There are a lot of recommendations over the Internet to always prefer the second method using return value and just let the compiler do the optimizations needed. But can I completely rely on the compiler if efficiency matters for me? Can I be sure that the compiler would always prefer RVO to redundant copies of the data to be returned?

Comment: Firstly, this is NRVO, which is unlike RVO is not mandatory. But even if NRVO fails, the string will be moved rather than copied, so you don't lose anything.

Comment: Technically a copy will happen if the string is short enough and your implementation uses short string optimization, but this is still how I would code it.  I hate using out parameters.

Comment: Write idiomatic code first, then profile.  Premature optimizations are the root of all evil.

Comment: @NathanOliver first off, in any compiler worth it's upkeep there will be no copying due to NRVO. Second off, even if the NRVO doesn't happen and we copy, chances are, such copying will be faster than indirection via string reference.

Comment: @0x5453 of all bad cargo-cult advice I have ever heard, this is probably one of the worst.

Comment: @SergeyA It's obviously hyperbolic, and my actual advice would be much more nuanced and would not fit in a StackOverflow comment.  But the main point is that it is illogical to say "I care about performance" without profiling your code.

Comment: @0x5453 nobody said that the code should not be profiled. However, writing a code which is inherently subtly slow is a way to disaster - you will never be able to optimize it *later*, as it will never be something highlighted by the profiler due to it being one of the many small issues. It will be a death by the thousand cuts. One should always know what kind of performance profile they are aiming and write code correspondingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others, there is no guarantee that the compiler will optimize this, because the returned value is a named variable (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

However, in my opinion you can almost always rely on RVO if you enable optimizations, as RVO is one of the first and easiest optimization the compiler can do. The reason is, in the underlying architectures, there is no way to directly return a big value (bigger than a CPU register). The way it is done is that the caller function will allocate a local variable for the return value, and pass a pointer to this to the callee. So effectively, the compiler already has a local variable allocated on the stack, and will use this one instead of allocating another identical one. The compiler will construct your string in-place directly in the caller function local variable.